# Game Object will NOT stretch across entire content area

Tags: unity, c#, 2d, gui, ui-design

I'm loading prefabs into a content area using a content size fitter and vertical layout group. I've tried multiple things to get the loaded prefabs to stretch across the entire content size (including the [Unity Manual for this issue](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UIFitContentSize.html)), but I'm at an impass. I'll post a screenshot below to show what I'm working with:

[image]

Here's how I'm loading in the prefabs in case this is where i'm screwing up:

```
void CreateRaceSelect() {

 for (int i = 0; i < races.races.Count; i++) {
     raceButton = (GameObject)Instantiate(raceButtonPrefab);
     raceText = raceButton.transform.FindChild("Text").GetComponent<Text>();

     raceButton.name = i.ToString();
     raceButton.transform.SetParent(content.transform);
     raceButton.GetComponent<RectTransform>().localPosition = new Vector3(xPos, yPos, 0);
     raceText.text = races.races[i].ToString();
     yPos -= (int)raceButton.GetComponent<RectTransform>().rect.height;
    }
 }
```

I'm sure this is a minor screw up but at this point I have no other ideas.

Comment: I see you have selected "stretch" on one of the Rect transforms. Did you try holding down alt when you did this? The option natively changes the *anchor*; you need to hold alt (cmd on Mac) to change *position*, and without doing so, stretching does not seem to have an effect.

Comment: I have the content set to stretch across the entire width of the View Area. Checking the Anchors, the 4 anchor points are distributed to each corner of the view port

Comment: That is not what I asked. When you change the *anchor*, it *does not* appear to enforce stretching. You *need* to hold ***alt / cmd*** and change the anchor, to *"Also set position"*. Note that it *will* show you "stretch" as being selected without this. The fact that the anchors are set in any way means nothing in the context where I have used image/gui stretching.

Comment: Yes I tried that as well.

Comment: Can you clarify what object should stretch where? I don't really get what you're asking here. Also, in a case like this, the file structure is really important, since stretching is a parent-child relationship.

Comment: The objects in the right image. Between the red boxes.

Answer (score 1):

Check the Child Force Expand Width/Height According to your requirement.And set value of spacing in vertical layout component to zero instead of -6. I guess this will solve your issue.